# Comment_author_url doing nothing

Tags: php, comments, urls, author, list-authors

I have this function:

```
<?php
function top_comment_authors($amount = 5) {
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT
    COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url
    FROM '.$wpdb->comments.'
    WHERE comment_author_email != "" AND comment_type = "" AND comment_approved = 1
    GROUP BY comment_author_email
    ORDER BY comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC
    LIMIT '.$amount
);

foreach($results as $result) {
    $output .= "<li><a href=".$result->comment_author_url.">".$result->comment_author."</a> (".$result->comments_count.")</li>";
}

echo $output;
}
?>
```

So here, I am trying to link to the comment_author_url (the author page), but it does not do a thing. How can this be? What am I doing wrong?

```
<li><a href=".$result->comment_author_url.">
```

Comment: comment_author_url is not the author's page, but his www instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query from:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url
    FROM '.$wpdb->comments.'
    WHERE comment_author_email != "" AND comment_type = "" AND comment_approved = 1
    GROUP BY comment_author_email
    ORDER BY comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC
    LIMIT '.$amount
```

To:

```
SELECT *,
    COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url
    FROM '.$wpdb->comments.'
    WHERE comment_author_email != "" AND comment_type = "" AND comment_approved = 1
    GROUP BY comment_author_email
    ORDER BY comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC
    LIMIT '.$amount
```

And then this:

```
$output .= "<li><a href=".$result->comment_author_url.">".$result->comment_author."</a> (".$result->comments_count.")</li>";
```

To:

```
$output .= "<li><a href=".get_author_posts_url($result->user_id).">".$result->comment_author."</a> (".$result->comments_count.")</li>";
```

Modifying the query grants you to reach all fields, one of these ( user_id ), will be used to get the author's page with `get_author_posts_url();`

**Update**

I suggest you to use double quote on SQL strings and single quote on HTML.
In your code you're trying to concatenate $output with nothing.

So your queries might look like this:

```
"
    SELECT *,
        COUNT(comment_author_email) AS comments_count, comment_author_email, comment_author, comment_author_url
        FROM $wpdb->comments
        WHERE comment_author_email != '' AND comment_type = '' AND comment_approved = 1
        GROUP BY comment_author_email
        ORDER BY comments_count DESC, comment_author ASC
        LIMIT $amount
"
```

Then for $output:

```
$output = '<ul>';
foreach($results as $result) {
$output .= '<li><a href="'.get_author_posts_url($result->user_id).'">'.$result->comment_author.'</a> ('.$result->comments_count.')</li>';
}
$output .= '</ul>';
```

Hope it helps!